# Computing $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^3 \sqrt{|x|}}{|x|+y^4}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need some help computing $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^3 \sqrt{|x|}}{|x|+y^4}$$

I tried to bound with AM-GM (or $(\sqrt{|x|}-y^2)^2\geq 0)$, but I couldn't proceed further because the term $y^3$ can be positive or negative so I can't multiply by $y^3$ to bound the expression.

Also, I tried polar coordinates, but I couldn't find a bound for the expression that depends of $\theta$.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your limit as $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{y^3 \sqrt{|x|}}{|x|+y^4}=\pm\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|y|^3 \sqrt{|x|}}{|x|+|y|^4}$$
Here the $\pm$ is the sign of $y$. So if the limit on the right is not zero, then the limit on the left does not exist (one can approach from positive or negative $y$).

Your idea with polar coordinates is good, but you should use such transformation that the denominator does not depend on $\theta$. To do that, use $|x|=r^2\cos^2\theta$ and $|y|^2=r\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is in the first quadrant. Then $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|y|^3 \sqrt{|x|}}{|x|+|y|^4}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{(r\sin\theta)^{3/2}r\cos\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta}=\sin^{3/2}\theta\cos\theta\lim_{r\to 0}r^{1/2}=0$$

Comment: Small doubt, we can always "modify" polar coordinates to solve this kind of limits?

Comment: You can, if it helps you. There is a bijection between $(x,y)$ and $(r,\theta)$. So if the limit does exist, it must be $\theta$ independent.

Answer (score 1):

Let the limit be $L$. Put $\sqrt{|x|} = z \implies |x| = z^2\implies 0 \le \left|\dfrac{y^3\sqrt{|x|}}{|x|+y^4}\right|= \left|\dfrac{y^3z}{z^2+y^4}\right|= |y|\cdot \dfrac{y^2|z|}{y^4+z^2}\le \dfrac{|y|}{2}\implies |L| = 0\implies L = 0$.